# Laravel + Docker: FIle could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, docker, apache, ssl

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    libzip-dev \
    zip

# Enable Apache modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod headers
RUN a2enmod ssl

RUN mkdir -p /etc/apache2/ssl  # Create the ssl directory

# Generate a self-signed certificate
RUN openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/cert-key.pem -out /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.pem \
    -subj "/C=US/ST=California/L=New York/O=Zylu/OU=Zylu/CN=zylu.co"

COPY ./apache/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

# Copy the application code
COPY . /var/www/html

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/storage \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache

RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/storage \
    && chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache

# Expose port 80 and 443 and start Apache
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

I encountered a permission error when deploying my Docker container on DigitalOcean. Specifically, the error reported was:

```
The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Interestingly, this issue does not occur when building the container locally on my Mac M1 Air. To resolve the problem on DigitalOcean, I have temporarily employed a workaround using the following command:

```
docker exec -u 0 -it <container-id> /bin/bash
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/storage
```

This resolves the permission issue, but I am seeking a solution that directly works from docker file cause i would like to automate deployment.

Also this issue only happens digital ocean when i try building the container locally on my mac m1 air this issue is not thier

Answer (score 0):

Try setting user the user to www-data before exposing the port using

```
USER www-data
```

and also modify your

```
COPY . /var/www/html
```

to

```
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/html
```

so that during the copy the ownership is transferred to www-data inside the container.
Also limit the permission to 775, it should work just fine until and unless you have any other issues.

you final Dockerfile should look something like

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    libzip-dev \
    zip

# Enable Apache modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod headers
RUN a2enmod ssl

RUN mkdir -p /etc/apache2/ssl  # Create the ssl directory

# Generate a self-signed certificate
RUN openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/cert-key.pem -out /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.pem \
    -subj "/C=US/ST=California/L=New York/O=Zylu/OU=Zylu/CN=zylu.co"

COPY ./apache/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

# Copy the application code
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/html

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/storage \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache

RUN chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/storage \
    && chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache

# Set user to www-data to start apache
USER www-data

# Expose port 80 and 443 and start Apache
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```